# Laravel 8 getting SQL error in eloquent query while getting nested JSON response of two related Table

Tags: json, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm having an SQL Error, the model name are joining two table, the column name is returning
'i_t_e_m__l_o_c__m_d_l_LOC_ID' instead of 'LOC_ID'

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'i_t_e_m__l_o_c__m_d_l_LOC_ID'. 
(SQL: select * from [tblDepartment] where [tblDepartment].[i_t_e_m__l_o_c__m_d_l_LOC_ID] in (1, 2))
```

Here is my code for model

```
    protected $primarykey = 'LOC_ID';
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
    protected $table = 'tblLocation';
   
    public function departments()
    { 
        return $this->hasMany(departmentsModel::class);
    }
```

This is for the controller

```
    public function allLoc(Request $request){
    $data = locationModel::with('departments')->get();
    return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: define foreign key in the relation function, see : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many
`$this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

Answer (score 0):

Define foreign key in the relation function

```
public function departments()
{ 
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

for more detail please check: laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many